# Is there any way to store a variable globally in a Dynamics CRM plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm

We have a plugin for Dynamics CRM that needs to call an API using an OAuth token. We would like to store the token until it expires, rather than getting a new token each time the plugin is executed. I tried to use SharedVariables on the context, but that doesn't seem to work to do this (found some conflicting information on how Shared Variables work, so not sure what they are really for).

Is there anything available to Dynamics CRM plugins that will allow you to store a variable across executions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins are executed and kept alive in .NET app domains and therefore you can actually use a static field or a `MemoryCache` object. Be aware that objects cached by a `MemoryCache` even survive updates of the plugin assembly, so using that with fixed keys can lead to unexpected results. Of course you would need to make a thread safe design.

> Shared variables is a collection of data that is available during the processing of an individual request (create, update etc.). It is used to share data between the various stages of the plugin pipeline (validate/pre/post/async).

Comment: Thanks, a static field works for this.

Answer (score 0):

Shared variables are valid within the current context of the plugin execution and usually used to transfer data between pre op and post op plugins. This cannot be used as a global storage.

What you need is a chaching mechanism which would not be possible in dynamics (unless u want to store token in an entity with expiry date, which would pose its own security risk).

Alternates is having an custom web api which does the chaching and act as proxy for the original web api that the plugin wants access. This way the chaching can be done with security standards of the web application. Design of this web api is upto the developer on how to store the token etc.